# problems with icalendar gem with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, icalendar

Hi there I'm new to the world of stack and I know questions like mine can be easily brushed aside, but I'm very stuck with creating an ical link.

My clients_controller.rb is as such:

```
 #calendar ical link 
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.ics do
    cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    cal.x_wr_calname = 'Awesome Rails Calendar'
    cal.event do |e|
      e.dtstart     = DateTime.now + 2.hours
      e.dtend       = DateTime.now + 3.hours
      e.summary     = 'Power Lunch'
      e.description = 'Get together and do big things'
    end
    cal.publish
    render plain: cal.to_ical
  end
end
```

My link looks like:

```
<%= link_to 'Sync calendar', clients_url(protocol: :webcal, format: :ics) %>
```

When I click to 'Syn calendar' I get the following problem 
[image: icalendar link broken]

When I leave the authentication from devise on authenticate_user! in the controller I get this error in addition:
[image]

Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks in advance!

Evan

Comment: Hi Evan, I can't help with the ruby side.I can offer that I'd work on the url 'access denied' message and that you appear to be syncing to a local host?  Is that url correct?   Also note webcal is unofficial -  http/s more universally accepted (check you have a text/calendar mime type)

Comment: Hi @anmari once online it sets up with the ip of my server, however it still returns the same error how do I changed the address to http/s on the webcal link?

Comment: I would start with first checking the actual link generated (not the code to produce the link) - is that actual link correct? Post it here.    Once I was sure that the link was correct I would check the actual contents of the ics file, look at it in a notepad text editor and also validate the actual link with the various ics validators.